# Modify a class value (self.var), that is specified as a parameter to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create reusable code that is modifying a class variable, whose name is not known to the method that is doing the logic.

In `Example.receive_button_press`, I am trying to call a function on an object that I have passed into the method, whose variable(s) would also be provided as parameters.

Can this be done in python? The code below does not quite work, but illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class SomeOtherClass():
    _locked_button = False
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def do_button_press(self, button):
        if button:
            return
        button = True
        someVal = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
        button = False
        return someVal 

class Example():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def receive_button_press(self, obj, func, var):
        return obj.func(var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    toyClass = Example()
    other = SomeOtherClass()

    myButton = tk.Button(text="Press", 
                         command=toyClass.receive_button_press(obj = other,func = other.do_button_press, 
                                                               var=SomeOtherClass._locked_button))
    myButton.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The way that you reference `self.lock_xsd_button` is by writing `self.lock_xsd_button`.  It makes no sense to pass that as a parameter.

Comment: @jasonharper I have modified the question to be clearer.

Comment: Is `tk` really necessary for a [mcve]?

Comment: @MadPhysicist In this instance, the way that I was testing it was to repeatedly click a button, and when it was locked, it was working. It is certainly _a way_...

Comment: You don't need to pass `obj`: it's already encoded in the bound method.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Indeed, but I am looking to anonymously call the methods on an unnamed/passed function.

Comment: Just to be clear, which part are you interested in in this question, `return obj.func(var)` (which should just be `func(var)`, or in `button = True`?

Comment: @Sam. I can tell that you are new, so we have to hash out some terminology is all. I suspect the words I'm writing mean something different to you than they do to me. Yours certainly have that for me.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am interested in assigning SomeOtherClass._locked_button, when SomeOtherClass is being passed into another method. The example above does not work due to scoping reasons, however, in an ideal world, I would have some method that takes SomeOtherClass in as a parameter and I assign SomeOtherClass._lockedButton in a way that does not require me to explicitly write self._lockedButton, but rather references only the parameters specified in the function definition.

Comment: @Sam. I can answer that, but there are a bunch of other things you'll need to fix for this to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241672/discussion-between-sam-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Callable Objects**

You need to understand how callables work in python. Specifically, [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) objects are regular objects. The only special thing about them is that you can apply the `()` operator to them. Functions, methods and lambdas are just three of many types of callables.

Here is a callable named `x`:

```
x
```

`x` might have been defined as

```
def x():
    return 3
```

Here is the result of calling `x`, also known as the "return value":

```
x()
```

Hopefully you can see the difference. You can assign `x` or `x()` to some other name, like `a`. If you do `a = x`, you can later do `a()` to actually call the object. If you do `a = x()`, a just refers to the number 3.

The `command` passed to `tk.Button` should be a callable object, not the result of calling a function. The following is the result of a function call, since you already applied `()` to the name `receive_button_press`:

```
toyClass.receive_button_press(obj=other, func=other.do_button_press, 
                              var=SomeOtherClass._locked_button)
```

If this function call were to return another callable, you could use it as an argument to `command`. Otherwise, you will need to make a callable that performs the function call with no arguments:

```
lambda: toyClass.receive_button_press(obj=other, func=other.do_button_press, 
                                      var=SomeOtherClass._locked_button)
```

As an aside, if you add a `__call__` method to a class, all if its instances will be callable objects.

**Bound Methods**

The object `other.do_button_press` is called a bound method, which is a special type of callable object. When you use the dot operator (`.`) on an instance (`other`) to get a function that belongs to a class (`do_button_press`), the method gets "bound" to the instance. The result is a callable that does **not** require `self` to be passed in. In fact, it has a `__self__` attribute that encodes `other`.

Notice that you call

```
other.do_button_press(button)
```

**not**

```
other.do_button_press(other, button)
```

That's why you should change `Example` to read

```
def receive_button_press(self, func, var):
    return func(var)
```

**References to Attributes**

You can access attributes in an object in a couple of different ways, but the simplest is by name. You can access a named attribute using the builtin `hasattr` and set them with `setattr`. To do so, you would have to change `do_button_press` to accept an object and an attribute name:

```
def do_button_press(self, lock_obj, lock_var):
    if getattr(lock_obj, lock_var, False):
        return
    setattr(lock_obj, lock_var, True)
    someVal = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
    setattr(lock_obj, lock_var, False)
    return someVal
```

**Interfaces and Mixins**

If this seems like a terrible way to do it, you're right. A much better way would be to use a pre-determined interface. In python, you don't make an interface: you just document it. So you could have `do_button_press` expect an object with an attibute called "locked" as "button", rather than just a reference to an immutable variable:

```
class SomeOtherClass():
    locked = False

    def do_button_press(self, lock):
        if lock.locked:
            return
        lock.locked = True
        someVal = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
        lock.locked = False
        return someVal
```

At the same time, you can make a "mixin class" to provide a reference implementation that users can just stick into their base class list. Something like this:

```
class LockMixin:
    locked = False

class SomeOtherClass(LockMixin):
    def do_button_press(self, lock):
        if lock.locked:
            return
        lock.locked = True
        someVal = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
        lock.locked = False
        return someVal
```

**Locks**

Notice that I started throwing the term "Lock" around a lot. That's because the idea you have implemented is called "locking" a segment of code. In python, you have access to thread locks via [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock). Rather than manually setting `locked`, you use the [`acquire`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) and [`release`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.release) methods.

```
class SomeOtherClass:
    def do_button_press(self, lock):
        if lock.acquire(blocking=False):
        try:
            someVal = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
            return someVal
        finally:
            lock.release()
```

Alternatively, you can use the lock as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement). The only catch is that [`acquire`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) will be called with `blocking=True` by default, which may not be what you want:

```
def do_button_press(self, lock):
    with lock:
        someVal = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
        return someVal
```

**Decorators**

Finally, there is one more tool that may apply here. Python lets you apply decorators to functions and classes. A decorator is a callable that accepts a function or class as an argument and returns a replacement. Examples of decorators include [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod), [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Many decorators return the original function more-or-less untouched. You can write a decorator that acquires a lock and releases it when you're done:

```
from functools import wraps
from threading import Lock

def locking(func):
    lock = Lock()
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if lock.acquire(blocking=False):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                lock.release()
    return wrapper
```

Notice that the wrapper function is itself decorated (to forward the name and other attributes of the original `func` to it). It passes through all the input arguments and return of the original, but inside a lock.

You would use this if you did not care where the lock came from, which is likely what you want here:

```
class SomeOtherClass:
    @locking
    def do_button_press(self):
        return tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')
```

**Conclusion**

So putting all of this together, here is how I would rewrite your toy example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from functools import wraps
from threading import Lock

def locking(func):
    lock = Lock()
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if lock.acquire(blocking=False):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                lock.release()
    return wrapper

class SomeOtherClass():
    @locking
    def do_button_press(self, button):
        return tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='\\')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    toyClass = SomeOtherClass()

    myButton = tk.Button(text="Press", command=toyClass.do_button_press)

    myButton.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```